# Appending input to file

Tags: c#

I want the program to run, and every time the user hits the button then I want to add it to the file, as of right now the program keeps overwriting the content with the new information that the user inputs.

```
    private void tradeMethod()
    {
        newTrade.Analysis = textBox1.Text;
        newTrade.Trend = textBox2.Text;
        newTrade.entryLevel = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        newTrade.bottomLine = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        newTrade.Picture = textBox5.Text;
        newTrade.entrySetup = textBox6.Text;
        string Analysis = newTrade.Analysis;
        string Trend = newTrade.Trend;
        double entryLevel = newTrade.entryLevel;
        double bottomLine = newTrade.bottomLine;
        string Picture = newTrade.Picture;
        string entrySetup = newTrade.entrySetup;


        string[] info = { "The analysis: "+Analysis,"The Trend: " +Trend, "The entry price: " + entryLevel.ToString(), 
                            "The profit/loss of the trade: " + bottomLine.ToString(),"The entry of the trade was: " + entrySetup, "The screnshot of the picture: " +Picture};
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication8\\WindowsFormsApplication8\\trade.txt", info);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tradeMethod();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string addrLine;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication8\\WindowsFormsApplication8\\trade.txt");
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                addrLine = inputFile.ReadLine();
                MessageBox.Show(addrLine);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe [AppendAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do the job.

Comment: There are literally hundreds, if not thousands, of references for this basic operation. Please do some basic research before asking a question.

Comment: I researched it, I don't want to add a single line. I want the user input to  go into the same file every time they click the button.

Comment: Then expand on that type of solution to suit your needs? You can't expect to find your exact solution every time you research an issue.

Comment: @sam what did you actually research besides saying that you did.. can you tell us what key word search you did..? perhaps you're not using the correct key words when searching on a topic in regards to Appending Lines to an Existing File

Comment: I tried doing a loop but it doesn't work, and I researching writing a file, appending, but appending is adding a single new line. I want the user's input in the text boxes to be added to the same file if he inputs 2 different values in

Answer (score 0):

[Alessandro D'Andria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2655826/alessandro-dandria)'s comment is correct. Using the method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines
```

will overwrite the file each time, erasing all previous content.  Per the [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, you should use:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines
```

This method will handle creating a new file if one does not exist.